# Rainbow screen issue with raspberry pi 3 model b+

Tags: pi-3b+, linux, boot-issues, ubuntu

I am using Raspberry pi 3 Model B+ and using **Ubuntu Mate** operating system **not Raspbian Os** I am also using raspberry pi 3 supportable original charger of 5.1V 2.5A. still i am facing the same rainbow screen issue on system startup. I have inserted same **ubuntu mate Os image file compatible with Raspberry pi 3B+** loaded memory card in Raspberry pi 2 Model B and it is working fine. Please help me to solve this issue as soon as possible. Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: what exactly is the `rainbow screen issue`? It is not unusual to say that screen on startup...

Comment: Rainbow screen issue means when i starts raspberry pi, only rainbow screen (colourful screen) display on the screen... And this issue i am facing in only Raspberry pi 3 Model B+..

Comment: Did you check that your Mate version is compatible with 3B+?

Comment: Yes it is compatible with 3B+...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Raspberry Pi 3b+ not booting](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/92672/raspberry-pi-3b-not-booting). Please read the [The Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rainbow screen, Raspberry Pi will not boot](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/70121/rainbow-screen-raspberry-pi-will-not-boot)

Comment: Thank you Ingo and Fred for reply. I have read these links as you have mentioned but I am using Ubuntu Mate Operating system which is compatible with Raspberry pi 3B+. I am not using Raspbian Operating system. it is mentioned in the links that it could have either Powersupply issue or official Os image file. but i am using both (original raspberry pi charger 5.1v 2.5A) but why it is not working. you can also check that Ubuntu mate official version for Raspberry pi 3B+ is already released and i am using that one and with this setup, it is working in other Raspberry pi 2 model properly.

Comment: I am providing the links of Ubuntu mate image file which i am using for Raspberry pi 3B+ :- https://ubuntu-mate.org/raspberry-pi/  & https://ubuntu-mate.org/download/